# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl-devil in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I am trying to use DevIL but it keeps giving this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   lwjgl-devil in java.library.path

when I run the line: `IL.create();`

I know that I need `lwjgl-devil.dll`. Where can I find it? I googled without success. I tried adding the `lwjgl-devil.jar` to Eclipse but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `lwjgl-devil.dll` and the `DevIL.dll` which you get here 
http://openil.sourceforge.net/download.php

Comment: I know, but it only gives you the jar file, not the dll file.

Comment: @TheProgrammerG Have you actually tried the link?... or did you only had enough time to write the comment? :-)

Comment: The `DevIL.dll` can be found under _DevIL-SDK-x86-1.7.8/lib_ folder after unzipping DevIL 1.7.8 SDK for Windows. The lwjgl-devil.dll can be found after unzipping the `.jar` found here: [link]http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/n/Downloadnativewin32jar.htm

Comment: Yes, but you can extract the files from a `.jar`. Did you try it?